# Cdf of the area of a stick broken into 2 with UNI(0,1)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a stick $L$ broken into 2 with UNI$(0,L)$.
I am trying to find the cdf and pdf of $Y$ which denotes the area of rectangle created from the two lengths.
( one side = $L-p$ other is $p$)

Now, I am confused about how to apply it to the area , as I think the cdf for just the stick length would be close to this:

let $$X: \min(p,L-p)\implies(X \leq y)$$
If $$y \geq \frac{L}{2} \implies P(X \leq y)=1$$
$$y\leq 0 \implies P(X \leq y) = 0$$
We conclude:
$$0 \leq y    \leq  \frac{L}{2}  \implies P(X \leq y)= \frac{2y}{L}$$
$$ (X \leq y)= (p \leq y) \cup {p \in [L-y, L]}$$

Am I on the right path or should I form a rectangle and try work from scratch from there?

Comment: Use Heron's formula:  $A = \sqrt{s (s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ where $s = {a+b+c \over 2}$ is the semiperimeter and $a,b,c$ are the sides (let $a+b+c \equiv 1$).  Plot admissible regions in an $a$ versus $b$ plot and perform integration.

Comment: The stick length is $L$, but the break, $p$, is distributed over 0 to 1.  (Is that okay or a misprint?)

Comment: @Graham Kemp I am sincerely sorry, I corrected it , I meant L .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the probability distribution of a function of a random variable.

The process is to determine this function and its inverse.  E.g. since $f$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, the cdf is $F(X)=X$; $0\leq x\leq 1$.  Then $Y = h(x) = (1-x)(x)$ the area. Then determine the inverse of $h(x)$, call it $v(y)$ (simple algebra).  Then 
$$F(y) = P(Y < y) = P(x-x^2 < y) = P(x < v(y)) = F(v(y)).$$

See [Functions of one random variable](https://www.stat.washington.edu/~nehemyl/files/UW_MATH-STAT395_functions-random-variables.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE and thank you for your contribution! You might be interested in [learning to use Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting the equations.